# SoS,use javascript to implement the method 'attr' which in jquery? implement a submenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-selectors

```
<style type="text/css">
.item{list-style:none;width:200px;line-height:30px;border:1px solid #324}
#item-1{}
#item-2{}
#item-3{}
.subcontents{}
.subcontents .subnames{width:400px;height:300px;border:1px dotted;#324;position:absolute;left: 250px;}
#subcontents-1{display:none;top:20px;}
#subcontents-2{display:none;top:50px;}
#subcontents-3{display:none;top:80px;}
    </style>


<ul>
    <li id="item-1" class="item">internet</li>
    <li id="item-2" class="item">center</li>
    <li id="item-3" class="item">blog</li>
</ul>
<div class="subcontents">
    <div id="subcontents-1" class="subnames"></div>
    <div id="subcontents-2" class="subnames"></div>
    <div id="subcontents-3" class="subnames"></div>
</div>


var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item'); //return Array
var itemid = [],idnumber = [];
for(var i = 0,len = item.length;i < len; i++){
    var itemid[i] = item[i].attr('id'); // here has some question
    var idnumber[i] = itemid[i].substr(itemid.indexOf('-') + 1);    
}



var handler = function () {



    function showdiv(idnumber) {
        var subnavcontent = "subcontents-" + idnumber;
        var getshowid = document.getElementByid('subnavcontent');
        getshowid.style.display = 'block';
    }

};


function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) // W3C
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    else if (obj.attachEvent) // Microsoft
        obj.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn);
}
addEvent(item, "mouseover", handler);
```

i mean that  when the mouse mouseover the

```
<li id="item-#" class="item">internet</li>
```

then show the `<div id="subcontents-#" class="subnames"></div>` . However ,must to use the code(method implementing) as  above.

1, capture  mouseover event by the li object ;

2, use the className to obtain the object's id;

3, intercept ID string(the corresponding number);

4, generated by the combination of a string of new ID, and processing

do you know me what to say,My English is bad. thanks.

if you don't know what to say :

just use the html to implement Navigation menu,but use the less code to implement it.

---

jquery code has been done it.

but javascript code ??

Comment: Sorry, your question is really unclear.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you could do it a little easier (now tested):

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-number="1" class="item">internet</li>
    <li data-number="2" class="item">center</li>
    <li data-number="3" class="item">blog</li>
</ul>

<div class="subcontents">
    <div id="subcontents-1" class="subnames">sub 1</div>
    <div id="subcontents-2" class="subnames">sub 2</div>
    <div id="subcontents-3" class="subnames">sub 3</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { 
      $('#menu > li').mouseenter(function() {
          var id = 'subcontents-' + $(this).attr('data-number');

          // Display the new subcontents
          $('#' + id).css('display', 'block');
      });

      $('#menu > li').mouseleave(function() {
          var id = 'subcontents-' + $(this).attr('data-number');

          // Hide the old subcontents
          $('#' + id).css('display', 'none');
      });
  });
</script>
```

Sorry for the bad first version. I shouldn't post untested code.

If you don't want to use the data-number attributes, replace `$(this).attr('data-number')` by `this.id.split("-")[1]`.

Comment: What data-number? this.id.split("-")[1] would work too and you need some quotes `var id = "subcontents-"+this.id.split("-")[1];` for example

Comment: i know this ,as my code    `itemid[i].substr(itemid.indexOf('-') + 1);`

Comment: thanks,it work. another question :do you know how to code it  in javascript ,just as my code method, i know it has some question, but i don't how to rewrite it..Now i learn javascript programming.But,thanks   again.

Comment: Your code has some errors, but I think, you can find and solve most of them comparing your code with mine. For example, to put `$(...)` around an element for calling jQuery functions. Or how to set css properties with jQuery. Any further specific questions?